# AFTER INSTALLING MAYAVI USING PIP - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mayavi'

Tags: pyqt, vtk, mayavi

I am using vs code
to plot a series of XYZ coordinats, and I looked for a way to convert the scatter points plot into a 3d plot, which can be exported to an STL file.

As I was searching for a solution i stumbled upon the "mayavi" library, which to my impression is the best for my needs.

I tried to run one of the example codes listed on their site and since then i am losing it.

I have successfully installed "mayavi", but I still get an error, I've looked everywhere and have no solution.

*installed properly Vtk and PyQt

here's the full error and code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi.mlab import *
from mayavi import mlab

def test_points3d():
    t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 20)

    x = np.sin(2 * t)
    y = np.cos(t)
    z = np.cos(2 * t)
    s = 2 + np.sin(t)

return (x, y, z, s, colormap="copper", scale_factor=.25)
# View it.

 test_points3d()
 s = mlab.mesh()
 mlab.show()
```

> [{
> "resource": "/c:/Users/dvirc/OneDrive/Desktop/dvir/.vs/Desktop/v16/DvirCodes/trysurf.py",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#2",
> "code": {
> "value": "reportMissingImports",
> "target": {
> "$mid": 1,
> "external": "https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules",
> "path": "/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md",
> "scheme": "https",
> "authority": "github.com",
> "fragment": "diagnostic-severity-rules"
> }
> },
> "severity": 4,
> "message": "Import "mayavi" could not be resolved",
> "source": "Pylance",
> "startLineNumber": 3,
> "startColumn": 6,
> "endLineNumber": 3,
> "endColumn": 12
> }]

Comment: Please use punctuation to separate phrases, otherwise it's difficult to understand you (also, separate paragraphs with two line breaks). *How* did you install that module? Please [edit] your question, fix it and add more details.

Comment: fixed!
hope you can help me now :)

Comment: You didn't explain *how* you installed that module. Also, that code will fail, as the `return` is in the wrong indentation level.